# How to make a text file with a pattern of hex numbers in increasing order using VIM?

Tags: file, vim, hex

How we can make a text file with a pattern of hex numbers in increasing order using the VIM editor?
I need a pattern like below:

```
0000
0001
0002
....
0008
0009
000A
000B
....
000F
0010
0011
....
FFFF
```

is it possible with repeat operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to create a macro. `<c-a>` will increment the number under the cursor by 1. If the number starts with a `0x` it will be interpreted as a a hex number.

From the documentation `:h CTRL-A`

```
The CTRL-A command is very useful in a macro.  Example: Use the following
steps to make a numbered list.

1. Create the first list entry, make sure it starts with a number.
2. qa        - start recording into register 'a'
3. Y         - yank the entry
4. p         - put a copy of the entry below the first one
5. CTRL-A    - increment the number
6. q         - stop recording
7. <count>@a - repeat the yank, put and increment <count> times
```

After words you might need to remove `0x` from the numbers and make them upper case.

Answer (score 5):

```
:put =map(range(0,65535), 'printf(''%04x'', v:val)')
```

Comment: use `%04X` for upper case hex letters